# How can i use constant url in my controller

Tags: angularjs

Here i defined some urls in .constant like

```
app.constant('UrlConstant',function(){
    var GlobalUrl = "http://localhost:5833/";})
```

This `UrlConstant` how can i use in my controller

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', [])
app.controller('twoWayBinding', function ($scope, UrlConstant) {
    $scope.changefun = function () {
        console.log(UrlConstant.GlobalUrl);
    }
```

in `console.log` i'm getting as undefind

Answer (score 0):

Use an `object` as the constant's value:

```
app.constant('UrlConstant', {
    GlobalUrl: "http://localhost:5833/"
});
```

Then you can call it with `UrlConstant.GlobalUrl`:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', [])
app.controller('twoWayBinding', function ($scope, UrlConstant) {
    $scope.changefun = function () {
        console.log(UrlConstant.GlobalUrl);
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you soo much